# Jackson ObjectMapper Tree: check for isMissingNode()

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

I'm trying to parse out the "components" part of the JSON below that I got off this website: http://geocoder.opencagedata.com/api.html:

```
{
   "licenses" : [
      {
         "name" : "CC-BY-SA",
         "url" : "http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/"
      },
      {
         "name" : "ODbL",
         "url" : "http://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/summary/"
      }
   ],
   "rate" : {
      "limit" : 2500,
      "remaining" : 2494,
      "reset" : 1434844800
   },
   "results" : [
      {
         "annotations" : {
            "DMS" : {
               "lat" : "22\u00b0 40' 46.34184'' S",
               "lng" : "14\u00b0 31' 39.36216'' E"
            },
            "MGRS" : "33KVQ5147391877",
            "Maidenhead" : "JG77gh36hv",
            "Mercator" : {
               "x" : 1617205.101,
               "y" : -2576841.391
            },
            "OSM" : {
               "url" : "http://www.openstreetmap.org/?mlat=-22.67954&mlon=14.52760#map=17/-22.67954/14.52760"
            },
            "callingcode" : 264,
            "geohash" : "k7fqfx6djekju86um1br",
            "sun" : {
               "rise" : {
                  "astronomical" : 1434774000,
                  "civil" : 1434777300,
                  "nautical" : 1434775620
               },
               "set" : {
                  "astronomical" : 1434822420,
                  "civil" : 1434819120,
                  "nautical" : 1434820800
               }
            },
            "timezone" : {
               "name" : "Africa/Windhoek",
               "now_in_dst" : 0,
               "offset_sec" : 3600,
               "offset_string" : 100,
               "short_name" : "WAT"
            },
            "what3words" : {
               "words" : "matriarchs.nano.rotates"
            }
         },
         "components" : {
            "city" : "Swakopmund",
            "clothes" : "Jet",
            "country" : "Namibia",
            "country_code" : "na",
            "road" : "Nathaniel Maxuilili St (Breite St)",
            "state" : "Erongo Region",
            "suburb" : "Central"
         },
         "confidence" : 0,
         "formatted" : "Jet, Nathaniel Maxuilili St (Breite St), Swakopmund, Namibia",
         "geometry" : {
            "lat" : -22.6795394,
            "lng" : 14.5276006
         }
      }
   ],
   "status" : {
      "code" : 200,
      "message" : "OK"
   },
   "thanks" : "For using an OpenCage Data API",
   "timestamp" : {
      "created_http" : "Sat, 20 Jun 2015 21:54:45 GMT",
      "created_unix" : 1434837285
   },
   "total_results" : 1
}
```

I can do it successfully provided that the place actually exist on a map.
However, if the place doesn't exist, let say I provide it with a latitude of 1 and a longitude of 1, the "components" part of this json would no longer be available.

I'm trying to prevent my server from bombing out if the "components" does not get returned in the json by doing this:

```
        JsonNode componentsNode = node.path("components");
        if (componentsNode.isMissingNode()) {
            return "Location Services unavailable";
        }
```

But all it is doing is pointing to the line below before it goes to the isMissingNode check and saying this line has NullPointerException :

```
        JsonNode componentsNode = node.path("components");
```

This makes sense as the components portion of the json doesn't exist.

How do I perform this check without Jackson giving me a nullpointerexception?

EDIT:

This is my code for jackson:

```
        JsonNode rootNode = m.readTree(responses.getBody());
        JsonNode resultNode = rootNode.get("results");
        if (resultNode.isArray()) {
            JsonNode node = resultNode.get(0);
            JsonNode componentsNode = node.path("components");
            if (componentsNode.isMissingNode()) {
                return "Location Services unavailable";
            }
            if (!componentsNode.path("city").isMissingNode() && !componentsNode.path("country").isMissingNode()) {
                return componentsNode.get("city").textValue() + ", " + componentsNode.get("country").textValue();
            }
        }
```

Also according to opencage, we have a json of the following if the latitude and longitude are both equal to 1:

```
{
   "documentation" : "http://geocoder.opencagedata.com/api.html",
   "licenses" : [
      {
         "name" : "CC-BY-SA",
         "url" : "http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/"
      },
      {
         "name" : "ODbL",
         "url" : "http://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/summary/"
      }
   ],
   "rate" : {
      "limit" : 2500,
      "remaining" : 2457,
      "reset" : 1451174400
   },
   "results" : [
      {
         "annotations" : {
            "DMS" : {
               "lat" : "0\u00b0 0' 42.92604'' N",
               "lng" : "0\u00b0 50' 9.45366'' E"
            },
            "MGRS" : "31MBV5913898681",
            "Maidenhead" : "JI09kx07hd",
            "Mercator" : {
               "x" : 93058.569,
               "y" : -1318.477
            },
            "OSM" : {
               "url" : "http://www.openstreetmap.org/?mlat=-0.01192&mlon=0.83596#map=17/-0.01192/0.83596"
            },
            "geohash" : "kpbxgjbdx30rpj39gksz",
            "sun" : {
               "rise" : {
                  "apparent" : 1451109240,
                  "astronomical" : 1451104680,
                  "civil" : 1451107860,
                  "nautical" : 1451106300
               },
               "set" : {
                  "apparent" : 1451152860,
                  "astronomical" : 1451157360,
                  "civil" : 1451154240,
                  "nautical" : 1451155800
               }
            },
            "what3words" : {
               "words" : "statutes.stout.falsifying"
            }
         },
         "components" : {
            "place_of_worship" : "mesjid waskita"
         },
         "confidence" : 10,
         "formatted" : "mesjid waskita",
         "geometry" : {
            "lat" : -0.0119239,
            "lng" : 0.83595935
         }
      }
   ],
   "status" : {
      "code" : 200,
      "message" : "OK"
   },
   "stay_informed" : {
      "blog" : "http://blog.opencagedata.com",
      "twitter" : "https://twitter.com/opencagedata"
   },
   "thanks" : "For using an OpenCage Data API",
   "timestamp" : {
      "created_http" : "Sat, 26 Dec 2015 16:32:06 GMT",
      "created_unix" : 1451147526
   },
   "total_results" : 1
}
```

Comment: Could provide a bit more of your Java code surrounding the `path` method call ? Because from the javadoc, the `path` method won't return a NPE if the node doesn't exist (https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#path(java.lang.String) ), so this means that your `node` variable is null instead.

Comment: hello, - i have added more code.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code ? Looks like `resultNode.get(0)` returns `null` in your case.. check `resultNode` length..

Comment: copy pasted you code and the json. removed the components property. I get `"Location Services unavailable"`. using Java 8 and Jackson 2.6.0

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing

```
JsonNode componentsNode = node.path("components");
```

Try doing

```
if (node.at("/results/components").isMissingNode()){...}
```